# Which type of applications can I build with the Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: server, realm

I discovered Realm Mobile Platform recently, but I'm not sure what it really is. 
After reading the documentation seems like a way to sync and store all data from the device to the server with a minor impact from the application side. What I tipically call Cloud.
But it's presented in [realm.io](http://realm.io) homepage like:

> Realtime collaboration in as little as 10 lines of code

Which is good, but I haven't see any code in documentation or examples to retrieve other user-ids other than mine. It seems that you can do 'Realtime collaboration' only hardcoding a user credential inside the app and use a single user to work on the same realm. Realm Permissions seems useless to me because a normal user cannot see other users or other realms.
Another thing I have seen is the Realm Event Framework, available for Professional and Enterprise edition, that partially resolve the problem of connection, adding the feature to edit objects on specific events.
But in apps where users communicate to each other, like a messanger or a social network, I cannot use events to create data from first user realm to the second user realm, is totally incorrect without an object permission management from server because in my realm I can obviously edit all objects, but that object could be created by another user. 
In a chat thread I cannot have the power to delete my friends comments freely, I cannot let the client app have the permission to do that.
Another example could be the 'friends' concept. Is impossible to create it, because the information should be shared between the two users and creating a Realm shared between all users that store connections between users allows all users to see all friendships or even worse manage other people friendships.

So Realm Mobile Platform can be great for an example app, a demo, a handy cloud solution to sync between devices but I cannot use it to substitute my RESTful webservice?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different apps that can be built with Realm Mobile Platform. We have started cataloging a list of demo apps [here](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/other-demo-apps/), hopefully they could help you get started.

Comment: Is there any app showing the things in the question? It seems that the points mentioned above are valid. How can someone create a chat app with multiple users using Realm Object Server since there is no way to query for data other than yours? I am searching many hours now and I have found nothing

Comment: To build a chat app you would create a synced Realm per thread. The app can then open the Realms when the user navigates to that view. Since Realms can be shared across users, this allows the permissions to work for direct messages or groups.

Comment: it seems though that it has to be under a specific user id and then grant permission to the other user(s) that participate in the thread. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, we are actively working on supporting user profile data so you could for example grant the user with email "x@x.com" where the server would identify the user ID for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: without Professional or Enterprise edition you can only create a cloud for your users at this time.

Actually Realm Object Server **Developer edition** is a way to upload a mobile realm database on a online server. Nothing more, nothing less. 
[Fine-granted (object-level) permission](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/22) will be developed in future and [selective synchronization](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/40) will be also a future feature.
The new *Access control* feature allow to set database user permission for every realm. It allow only certain users to read/write/change permissions to the selected online realm object.
So if you are thinking to create a global realm shared between all users, **PLEASE DON'T**. 
 
A shared realm synced with all users means that all users will download all informations, so if your app grows a new user will download about 100/200/500/1000MB in his device only to see his 0.0/0.2% of data. **And I haven't talked about security.**

### Paid solution [Professional And Enterprise edition]

"Event handling to the rescue."

Even if it sounds a little weird, events are the way you can create a service with user permissions.
But you need to think to your app from the mobile perspective, with events that manage data to other users database.
*A little example:* 
 
I have a chat thread with three components. **A**,**B** and **C**. 
Every user has his own realm on server, with a copy of his local database.
Now **A** post a comment. When it sync to Realm Object Server the event handler trigger a procedure that will open **B** and **C** realms and insert this new comment on the chat thread. Then when user **B** and **C** will open the app the new comment will be synced.
In the same way you need to control user permissions, so user **A** will not edit a user **B** comment on **B** and **C** realms, and will restore **B** comment on **A** realm because it have not the permission to edit that object.

**Obviously this solution will duplicate informations for every user which have access to that object.**

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So besides keeping in sync your own data, the developer's version doesn't offer much in terms of collaboration or synced access to shared objects. That's unfortunate. It seemed like a good alternative for medium scaled apps but the cost is prohibiting for new apps with low budget. Maybe if some essential features were added to the free version, it could be a viable option but right now other options seem more reasonable (mongodb, etc)

Comment: Today, Realm Mobile Platform works at the Realm level in terms of access control. You can share entire Realms and an app can use several to deliver features.

Comment: Which is exactly like having a MySQL server and create users that have access to 1/N databases. Question is: What kind of platform/website use more than 1 database to store informations? 
Sure there can be some particular application, but it's not the general use.